# Handling conflict in find, modify, save flow in MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to update a document that involves reading other collection and complex modifications, so the update operators in `findAndModify()` cannot serve my purpose.

Here's what I have:

```
Collection.findById(id, function (err, doc) {

    // read from other collection, validation
    // modify fields in doc according to user input
    // (with decent amount of logic)

    doc.save(function (err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json(500, { message: err });
      }

      return res.json(200, doc);
    });
}
```

My worry is that this flow might cause conflict if multiple clients happens to modify the same document.
It is said [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/) that:

> Operations on a single document are always atomic with MongoDB databases

I'm a bit confused about what `Operations` mean.

- Does this means that the `findById()` will acquire the lock until `doc` is out of scope (after the response is sent), so there wouldn't be conflicts? (I don't think so)
- If not, how to modify my code to support multiple clients knowing that they will modify Collection?
- Will Mongoose report conflict if it occurs?
- How to handle the possible conflict? Is it possible to manually lock the Collection?

  - I see suggestion to use Mongoose's `versionKey` (or timestamp) and retry for stale document
  - Don't use MongoDB altogether...

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks @jibsales for the pointer, I now use  Mongoose's `versionKey` (timestamp will also work) to avoid committing conflicts.

[aaronheckmann — Mongoose v3 part 1 :: Versioning](http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning)

See this sample code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9dc837b1ef2831c97fe8

Comment: Do you have asynchronous code in your comment block (of additional logic)?  It appears that you do, in which case you could end up saving stale data.  You might have success with something like this: https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-timestamp.

Comment: Yes, I also found some suggestion to use Mongoose's versionKey and retry for stale document. Is that what you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operations refers to reads/writes. Bare in mind that MongoDB is not an ACID compliant data layer and if you need true ACID compliance, you're better off picking another tech. That said, you can achieve atomicity and isolation via the Two Phase Commit technique [outlined in this article in the MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). This is no small undertaking, so be prepared for some heavy lifting as you'll need to work with the native driver instead of Mongoose. Again, my ultimate suggestion is to not drink the NoSQL koolaid if you need transaction support which it sounds like you do.

Comment: I see some suggestion to use Mongoose's versionKey and retry after research, do you recommend such solution?

Answer (score 1):

When MongoDB receives a request to update a document, it will lock the database until it has completed the operation. Any other requests that MongoDB receives will wait until the locking operation has completed and the database is unlocked. This lock/wait behavior is automatic, so there aren't any conflicts to handle. You can find a lot more information about this behavior in the [Concurrency](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/) section of the FAQ.

See jibsales answer for links to MongoDB's recommended technique for doing multi-document transactions.

There are a couple of NoSQL databases that do full ACID transactions, which would make your life a lot easier. [FoundationDB](https://foundationdb.com/) is one such database. Data is stored as Key-Value but it supports multiple data models through layers.

Full disclosure: I'm an engineer at FoundationDB.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was wrong when "try to query the dynamic field with the upsert option". This guide helped me: [How to solve error E11000 duplicate](https://quicktricks.net/mongoservererror-plan-executor-error-during-findandmodify-caused-by-e11000-duplicate-key-error-collection-solved/)

In above guide, you're probably making one of two mistakes:

- Upsert a document when findOneAndupdate() but the query finds a non-unique field.
- Use insert many new documents in one go but don't use "ordered = false"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).