# Lock a document while writing such that even reads are blocked in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a small problem while updating a document in MongoDB.

I have a document like this

```
orders{
  orderId:Number,
  orders: Array,
  time:Date,
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Now, orders is an Array, I read this array at multiple places, and also update it at several places. But when i am updating it, i do not want my other queries to read it. How to achieve this in MongoDB.

I checked the official MongoDB docs, but it is quite confusing and was not able to understand. Any other references or links or explanation would really help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB Read/Write Locks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638744/mongodb-read-write-locks)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special.
MongoDB writes on a single document are atomic (you won't see anything during the write, only before and after), and write locks are "greedy". It doesn't allow any other read/writes to take place while writing.

[MongoDB Read/Write Locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638744/mongodb-read-write-locks)

Answer (score 0):

If you want document level locking you can enable the `wiredtiger` storage engine. By default MongoDB has collection level locking (MMAP).